Easy short-term fix for loose kitchen tiles
What is an quick, easy way to reattach these 2 tiles? It just needs to be a temporary fix, because the whole wall is going to be re-tiled in 6 months.



Before re-attaching it to the wall, you might want to completely remove that broken tile and superglue it back together.  Ceramic will often glue back together without a visible seam if the edges of the crack are clean.

Just FYI, it looks like these tiles were not "back buttered" with thin set. Thus they are more prone to pull away from the thin set on the wall.

@bta thanks for that -- I did glue the tile before attaching it to the wall

Silicone works fine, but I like construction adhesive (or "project" or "panel" adhesive). They grab better than silicone. In particular, panel adhesive is designed to hold well initially. This eliminates the need to prop your part up while the adhesive sets.
Otherwise, any household glue will also work, including white glue.
If you want to seal the grout lines while you're at it, silicone is great.

For temporary fix a few dabs of silicone caulk behind them and some silicone along the edges to seal.
The cleaner you can get the back of the tiles and the wall the better.
A razor blade or acetone/nail polish removal should remove those tiles with little work.
